# How do I recursively set read-only permission using Perl?

Tags: perl, permissions, file-permissions, readonly

I would like `$dir` and everything underneath it to be read only. How can I set this using Perl?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do this with a combination of [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find) and chmod (see [perldoc -f chmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod.html)):

```
use File::Find;

sub wanted
{
    my $perm = -d $File::Find::name ? 0555 : 0444;
    chmod $perm, $File::Find::name;
}
find(\&wanted, $dir);
```

Comment: Use this one. Better than mine.

Comment: Should that be: chmod 0555, $File::Find::name;

Comment: This sets both directories and files to 555.  While that's ok for a directory, you're probably not going to want all your files executable.  I think I'd try the shell commands given one of the other answers.

Comment: @Jistanidiot: good catch; I've updated my answer so only directories get the +x bit.

Answer (score 2):

```
system("chmod", "--recursive", "a-w", $dir) == 0
  or warn "$0: chmod exited " . ($? >> 8);
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested but it should work. Note your directories themselves have to stay executable

```
set_perms($dir);

sub set_perms {
     my $dir = shift;
     opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die $!;
     while( (my $entry = readdir($dh) ) != undef ) {
          next if $entry =~ /^\.\.?$/;
          if( -d "$dir/$entry" ) {
              set_perms("$dir/$entry");
              chmod(0555, "$dir/$entry");
          }
          else {

              chmod(0444, "$dir/$entry");
          }
     }
     closedir($dh);
}
```

Of course you could execute a shell command from Perl as well:

```
system("find $dir -type f | xargs chmod 444");
system("find $dir -type d | xargs chmod 555");
```

I use xargs in case you have a lot of entries.

Comment: If you're using the shell, `chmod -R` is usually easiest.

Comment: @Ether - the problem with chmod -R is that you cannot distinguish between directories and regular files. You would have to set all files to executable which could be a security risk.